# NavigationView pops back to root, omitting intermediate view

Tags: swift, swiftui

In my navigation, I want to be able to go from `ContentView` -> `ModelListView` -> `ModelEditView` OR `ModelAddView`.

Got this working, my issue now being that when I hit the `Back` button from `ModelAddView`, the intermediate view is omitted and it pops back to `ContentView`; a behaviour that
`ModelEditView` does *not* have.

There's a reason for that I guess – how can I get back to `ModelListView` when dismissing `ModelAddView`?

Here's the code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List{
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: ModelListView(),
                    label: {
                        Text("1. Model")
                    })
                Text("2. Model")
                Text("3. Model")
            }
            .padding()
            .navigationTitle("Test App")
        }
    }
}

struct ModelListView: View {
    @State var modelViewModel = ModelViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        List(modelViewModel.modelValues.indices) { index in
            NavigationLink(
                destination: ModelEditView(model: $modelViewModel.modelValues[index]),
                label: {
                    Text(modelViewModel.modelValues[index].titel)
                })
        }
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .navigationBarItems(
            trailing:
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: ModelAddView(modelViewModel: $modelViewModel), label: {
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                    })
        )
    }
}

struct ModelEditView: View {
    @Binding var model: Model
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Titel", text: $model.titel)
    }
}

struct ModelAddView: View {
    @Binding var modelViewModel: ModelViewModel
    @State var model = Model(id: UUID(), titel: "")
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Titel", text: $model.titel)
    }
}

struct ModelViewModel {
    var modelValues: [Model]
    
    init() {
        self.modelValues = [ //mock data
            Model(id: UUID(), titel: "Foo"),
            Model(id: UUID(), titel: "Bar"),
            Model(id: UUID(), titel: "Buzz")
        ]
    }
}

struct Model: Identifiable, Equatable {
    let id: UUID
    var titel: String
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently placing a `NavigationLink` in the `.navigationBarItems` may cause some issues.

A possible solution is to move the `NavigationLink` to the view body and only toggle a variable in the navigation bar button:

```
struct ModelListView: View {
    @State var modelViewModel = ModelViewModel()
    @State var isAddLinkActive = false // add a `@State` variable

    var body: some View {
        List(modelViewModel.modelValues.indices) { index in
            NavigationLink(
                destination: ModelEditView(model: $modelViewModel.modelValues[index]),
                label: {
                    Text(modelViewModel.modelValues[index].titel)
                }
            )
        }
        .background( // move the `NavigationLink` to the `body`
            NavigationLink(destination: ModelAddView(modelViewModel: $modelViewModel), isActive: $isAddLinkActive) {
                EmptyView()
            }
            .hidden()
        )
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: trailingButton)
    }

    // use a Button to activate the `NavigationLink`
    var trailingButton: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.isAddLinkActive = true
        }) {
            Image(systemName: "plus")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a cool solution. I figured that using some kind of state, what I ended up doing now is using a `.sheet` with the state which works similarly. The advantage is that visually I can differentiate better between editing and adding–good to know though that I could have it your described way as well (and that placing `NavigationLink` in `.navigationBarItems` might be problematic as of Xcode 12 Beta 6...