# SwiftUI : navigation to next view from navigation bar button?

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I want to push a view when tapping the trailing button of the navigation bar, so I tried this:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            MyListView()
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Main list title"))
                .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button("Add", action: {
                    NavigationLink(destination: MyFormView()) {
                        Text("Hello!")
                    }
                }))
        }
    }

}
```

But nothing happens when I tap the button and I end up having an issue on the NavigationLink line:

> Result of 'NavigationLink<Label, Destination>' initializer is unused

Thank you for helping me

Comment: That's because you put `NavigationLink` inside Button's `action` instead of `content`. Btw instead of creating `NavigationLink` in navigation bar,  you can try this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63798249/8697793

Comment: Thank you, I got it working. I don't find this to be very intuitive though..