# SwiftUI pushed View through Navigationview pops back after dismissing sheet

Tags: swift, swiftui, navigation

I have tabView that presents multiple tabs . in home view i have navigationView that has search button as navigationitem,that pushes to search view . inside the search view after presenting a sheet and dismissing it, searchView gets pop to home view and pushed again to top. and this causes the interface of search being misplaces.
here is my code for tabView:

```
    struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            homeView()
                .tabItem { Text("Home") }
        }
    }
}
```

here is the code for HomeView:

```
 struct homeView:View{
    @State var showSearch:Bool = false
    var body: some View{
        NavigationView{
            Text("home")
                .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
                .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
                .navigationBarItems(trailing: HStack{
                    NavigationLink.init("", destination: SearchContentView(), isActive: $showSearch)
                    Button.init("search", action: {
                    showSearch.toggle()
                })})
        }
    }
}
```

and then this is searchView:

```
struct SearchContentView: View {
    @State private var isplayItem:Bool = false
    @State private var isEditing:Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        List(0..<30, rowContent: { i in
            Text("\(i)th")
                .onTapGesture {
                    isplayItem.toggle()
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: self.$isplayItem) {
                    Text("search Item \(i)")
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .offset(x: 0, y: 0)
                }
        })
            .navigationBarTitle("search", displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
    
}
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: This requires debugging, would you provide minimal reproducible example? (provided code is not testable)

Comment: @Asperi I changed the code to a simple and testable example. Appreciate your help :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NavigationView pops back to root, omitting intermediate view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63773308/navigationview-pops-back-to-root-omitting-intermediate-view)

Comment: @pawello2222 no this not help my issue :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently placing a `NavigationLink` in the `navigationBarItems` may cause some issues.

Try removing the `NavigationLink` from `navigationBarItems` and put it the `background`:

```
struct homeView: View {
    @State var showSearch: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("home")
                 // move `NavigationLink` outside `navigationBarItems`
                .background(NavigationLink("", destination: SearchContentView(), isActive: $showSearch))
                .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
                .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
                .navigationBarItems(trailing: HStack {
                    Button("search", action: {
                        showSearch.toggle()
                    })
                })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response, your solution seems to work properly  :)